# implement spinner , spinner adapter and mainactivity.java

Tags: java, layout, spinner, android-arrayadapter

I make a android web browser and i add spinner to dropdown tabs groups with title as top , middle tabs group name with delete and rename icon, footer as add new tabs groups and close buttons. How can i implement this layout in adapter and maonactivity.java...

Design must need looks like..1)in the spinner need to show selected items with number of tabs in number text view and group name ( make sure i did not need here any icon like rename and delete icon) , in the inside of dropdown first need title with no icons  2) center no. of tabs with group name with delete and rename icon , 3) show footer.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.